# How can I insert data into an array column in PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I created this table and type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE mercadoria AS (
    codigo int,
    preco decimal,
    icms decimal
);

CREATE TYPE item_pedido AS (
    numeroItem int,
    quantidade decimal,
    desconto decimal,
    mercadoria mercadoria
);

CREATE TABLE pedido (
    codCliente int references cliente(codigo),
    codigo int primary key,
    data_pedido Date,
    data_entrega Date,
    itemPedido item_pedido[]
);
```

I would to insert an data into pedido, how can i do it?

I tried the following code, but it doesnt work...

```sql
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (
    32,
    1,
    '2023-01-01',
    '2023-01-02',
    ROW(
        {
            ROW(1, 2.5, 0.2, ROW(2, 33.3, 5.67)),
            ROW(1, 2.5, 0.2, ROW(6, 7.3, 0.7)),
            ROW(1, 2.5, 0.2, ROW(9, 10.6, 15.89)),
        }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very good table design (to say the least). Instead of storing records in an array, it is much better to store them in a separate table and join them. In other words, consider normalizing your table.

Assuming that this is an exercise on how to deal with custom data types, you just need to create an array of records with the custom data types:

```
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (32, 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02',
    ARRAY[
            (1, 2.5, 0.2, (2, 33.3, 5.67)::mercadoria)::item_pedido,
            (1, 2.5, 0.2, (6, 7.3, 0.7)::mercadoria)::item_pedido,
            (1, 2.5, 0.2, (9, 10.6, 15.89)::mercadoria)::item_pedido
        ]::item_pedido[]
    );
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/GzNm0Mnp)